# Datatable emptyMessage is not shown in PF5.3

Tags: primefaces

I am using PF 5.3, on (weblogic 11g/jsf2.0/java 1.6).
I thought the issue of not shown emptyMessage in Datatable is fixed in 5.3, but inspite of using the latest version, i still dont see the message. Below is my sample code.

```
<p:dataTable id="attaDt" var="fileRow" value="#{pendpaybean.selectedPayDetailsFiles}"
                            rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                            emptyMessage="No Files Uploaded"
                            >

                            <p:column headerText="Uploaded Date" 
                                 width="15px;" style="text-align:center" 
                                >
                                <h:outputText value="#{fileRow.columns[0]}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Uploaded By" 
                                 width="30px;" style="text-align:center" 
                                >
                                <h:outputText value="#{fileRow.columns[3]}" />
                            </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works well. **NOTE** I put attribute `value` to null for showing `emptyMessage`.

Your adapted code:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="attaDt" value="#{null}" var="fileRow" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" emptyMessage="No Files Uploaded">
            <p:column headerText="Uploaded Date" width="15px;" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{fileRow.columns[0]}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Uploaded By" width="30px;" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{fileRow.columns[3]}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Very Strange. I tried again by putting null as value, but still it is not shown in the UI. But......... it does show a <td>No Files Uploaded</td> in the view source.

Comment: caught the problem. The issue was in the incorrect overridden css for datatable. Thanks @Miguel